# Enabling static directory listing in complex Nginx setup

Tags: nginx

Our website is configured in the following way:

- The front end is powered by static HTML files created by Next.js. When a request to the front-end comes in, users are viewing these HTML files
- Next.js pulls its data from the Wordpress API
- When a request is not fulfilled by a static HTML file, it is passed along to wordpress
- Because of how routes are configured, we had to remove the forward slash from all URLs (getting past this might be a solution to the question below)
- We also need to serve some MP3 files from a static directory listing, the names of which change each week
- The static HTML files serve from /var/www/next/source/serve
- The Wordpress files are located in /var/www/wordpress

Here is the primary configuration:

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
  default                                off;
  #text/html                              epoch;
  text/css                               max;
  application/javascript                 max;
  ~image/                                max;
  font/ttf                               max;
  font/opentype                          max;
  application/font-woff                  max;
  font/woff2                             max;
  application/vnd.ms-fontobject          max;
}

server {
  # Initial setup
  listen 443 http2 ssl;
  server_name www.website.com;

  expires $expires;

  # Include SSL configutation
  include snippets/ssl-website.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  # Set root directory
  root /var/www/next/source/serve;

  # Access and error logs
  access_log /var/log/nginx/next_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/next_error.log;

  # GZIP
  include conf.d/gzip.conf;

  # Cache locatons
  include locations/cache-locations.conf;

  # Non-critical / one-off locations
  include locations/special-locations.conf;

  # Get rid of all trailing slashes. This makes the root (/) location below function properly
  if (!-d $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
  }

  location ~* \.(?:eot|ttf|svg|woff|woff2)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    access_log off;
  }

  # First try for the static HTML file. If not found, go to Wordpress
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri.html/ $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
  }

  # Wordpress
  location ~ \.php$ {
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log;
  }

  # Include redirects
  include redirects/primary-redirects.conf;

}
```

The `special-locations.conf` file contains a listing of a static directory called `audiofiles`:

```
location ^~ /audiofiles {
  root /var/www/wordpress;
  autoindex on;
  break;
}
```

Everything works as intended right now (front-end, WP-Admin, Wordpress static resources (CSS, JS), API requests, image files, etc.), except for the static directory listing at `/audiofiles`.

The problem is created by the `rewrite` rule in the root server block. We can't move it in to the `location /` block (I don't think anyway) because routes of every kind are based off of the root URL.

I've tried a million configurations to get this right. What can I do here to sort this out?

******** UPDATED POST-SOLUTION ********

Thanks to @Richard Smith for his simple and elegant solution. The final configuration looks like this:

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
  default                                off;
  text/css                               max;
  application/javascript                 max;
  ~image/                                max;
  font/ttf                               max;
  font/opentype                          max;
  application/font-woff                  max;
  font/woff2                             max;
  application/vnd.ms-fontobject          max;
}

server {
  # Initial setup
  listen 443 http2 ssl;
  server_name www.website.com;

  expires $expires;

  # Include SSL configutation
  include snippets/ssl-website.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  # Set root directory
  root /var/www/next/source/serve;

  # Access and error logs
  access_log /var/log/nginx/next_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/next_error.log;

  # GZIP
  include conf.d/gzip.conf;

  # Cache locatons
  include locations/cache-locations.conf;

  # Non-critical / one-off locations
  include locations/special-locations.conf; # This file contains the `audiofiles` static file directory

  location ~* \.(?:eot|ttf|svg|woff|woff2)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    access_log off;
  }

  # First try for the static HTML file. If not found, pass along to @redirects below
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri.html/ $uri/ @redirect;
  }

  # Some clever redirect management. Try either static files or send to Wordpress
  location @redirect {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^ /index.php?q=$uri&$args last;
  }

  # Wordpress
  location ~ \.php$ {
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log;
  }

  # Include redirects
  include redirects/migrate-redirects.conf;
}
```

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: There is literally no one who has not heard of ifisevil. If I knew of another solution, I would be using it. That is the reason for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to provide a difinitive answer for a complex Nginx setup. But the `$uri/` component of the `try_files` statement should perform the `!-d $request_filename` test, and then you can use a named `location` to perform the two redirections.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri.html/ $uri/ @redirect;
}
location @redirect {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^ /index.php?q=$uri&$args last;
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue. Can't tell you how much time I spent on this. Was even able to completely eliminate the intricate malevolence of `if`. Many thanks for the simple solution.